# How to access all Webservice methods from a Python Soap Client with multiple bindings using Python zeep

Tags: python, web-services, soap, wsdl, zeep

I have to consume data from a SOAP service, which is a new technology for me. I connected from the server using the following code:

```py
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport

wsdl= 'my_service.com/MEX?wsdl'
username = 'john_doe'
password = 'password'

session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)
transport = Transport(session=session)
client = Client(wsdl=wsdl, transport=transport)
```

Using SoapUi software and connecting with this server I realized that it has three bindings and each one has a lot of Webservices. But, with Python, I was able only to access the WebServices (via client.service) for the first binding. I want to know how can I access the Webservice methods from another two bindings.

OBS: client.wsdl.bindings return a dict mapping some urls containing the binding names seen on SoapUI to Soap11Binding instances.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `Zeep` picks up the first binding in the WSDL. This binding is available via
`client.service`. To use a specific binding you can use the `bind()` method on the client object
sample code:

```
service2 = client.bind('SecondService', 'Port12')
service2.someOperation(arg1='abc', arg2=2)
```